# What causes an OpenGL context to be a "GDI Generic" context on AMD cards?

Tags: opengl, graphics, amd-processor

I have a problem where a particular graphic card (AMD Radeon HD 4200 with latest drivers) of a user is creating a `GDI Generic` context in our game, which can't be rendered to.

When running glew's `visualinfo.exe`, the result is this:

```
OpenGL vendor string: Microsoft Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: GDI Generic
OpenGL version string: 1.1.0
OpenGL extensions (GL_): 
    GL_WIN_swap_hint, GL_EXT_bgra, GL_EXT_paletted_texture.
GLU version string: 1.2.2.0 Microsoft Corporation
GLU extensions (GLU_): 
    GL_EXT_bgra.
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   visual   x  bf  lv rg d st ge ge  r  g  b a  ax dp st   accum buffs    ms 
 id  dep tp sp sz  l  ci b ro ne ac sz sz sz sz bf th cl  sz  r  g  b  a ns b
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
0x01  32 wn  .  32  .  r .  .  y  .  8  8  8  .  . 32  8  64 16 16 16  .  . .
0x02  32 wn  .  32  .  r .  .  y  .  8  8  8  .  . 16  8  64 16 16 16  .  . .
0x03  32 wn  .  32  .  r y  .  y  .  8  8  8  .  . 32  8  64 16 16 16  .  . .
0x04  32 wn  .  32  .  r y  .  y  .  8  8  8  .  . 16  8  64 16 16 16  .  . .
0x05  32 wn  .  32  .  r .  .  y  .  8  8  8  8  . 32  8  64 16 16 16 16  . .
0x06  32 wn  .  32  .  r .  .  y  .  8  8  8  8  . 16  8  64 16 16 16 16  . .
0x07  32 wn  .  32  .  r y  .  y  .  8  8  8  8  . 32  8  64 16 16 16 16  . .
0x08  32 wn  .  32  .  r y  .  y  .  8  8  8  8  . 16  8  64 16 16 16 16  . .
0x09  32 wn  .  32  .  c .  .  y  .  .  .  .  .  . 32  8   .  .  .  .  .  . .
0x0a  32 wn  .  32  .  c .  .  y  .  .  .  .  .  . 16  8   .  .  .  .  .  . .
0x0b  32 wn  .  32  .  c y  .  y  .  .  .  .  .  . 32  8   .  .  .  .  .  . .
0x0c  32 wn  .  32  .  c y  .  y  .  .  .  .  .  . 16  8   .  .  .  .  .  . .
0x0d  24 bm  .  24  .  r .  .  y  .  8  8  8  .  . 32  8  64 16 16 16  .  . .
0x0e  24 bm  .  24  .  r .  .  y  .  8  8  8  .  . 16  8  64 16 16 16  .  . .
0x0f  24 bm  .  24  .  r .  .  y  .  8  8  8  8  . 32  8  64 16 16 16 16  . .
0x10  24 bm  .  24  .  r .  .  y  .  8  8  8  8  . 16  8  64 16 16 16 16  . .
0x11  24 bm  .  24  .  c .  .  y  .  .  .  .  .  . 32  8   .  .  .  .  .  . .
0x12  24 bm  .  24  .  c .  .  y  .  .  .  .  .  . 16  8   .  .  .  .  .  . .
0x13  16 bm  .  16  .  r .  .  y  .  5  5  5  .  . 32  8  32 11 11 10  .  . .
0x14  16 bm  .  16  .  r .  .  y  .  5  5  5  .  . 16  8  32 11 11 10  .  . .
0x15  16 bm  .  16  .  r .  .  y  .  5  5  5  8  . 32  8  32  8  8  8  8  . .
0x16  16 bm  .  16  .  r .  .  y  .  5  5  5  8  . 16  8  32  8  8  8  8  . .
0x17  16 bm  .  16  .  c .  .  y  .  .  .  .  .  . 32  8   .  .  .  .  .  . .
0x18  16 bm  .  16  .  c .  .  y  .  .  .  .  .  . 16  8   .  .  .  .  .  . .
0x19   8 bm  .   8  .  r .  .  y  .  3  3  2  .  . 32  8  32 11 11 10  .  . .
0x1a   8 bm  .   8  .  r .  .  y  .  3  3  2  .  . 16  8  32 11 11 10  .  . .
0x1b   8 bm  .   8  .  r .  .  y  .  3  3  2  8  . 32  8  32  8  8  8  8  . .
0x1c   8 bm  .   8  .  r .  .  y  .  3  3  2  8  . 16  8  32  8  8  8  8  . .
0x1d   8 bm  .   8  .  c .  .  y  .  .  .  .  .  . 32  8   .  .  .  .  .  . .
0x1e   8 bm  .   8  .  c .  .  y  .  .  .  .  .  . 16  8   .  .  .  .  .  . .
0x1f   4 bm  .   4  .  r .  .  y  .  1  1  1  .  . 32  8  16  5  6  5  .  . .
0x20   4 bm  .   4  .  r .  .  y  .  1  1  1  .  . 16  8  16  5  6  5  .  . .
0x21   4 bm  .   4  .  r .  .  y  .  1  1  1  8  . 32  8  16  4  4  4  4  . .
0x22   4 bm  .   4  .  r .  .  y  .  1  1  1  8  . 16  8  16  4  4  4  4  . .
0x23   4 bm  .   4  .  c .  .  y  .  .  .  .  .  . 32  8   .  .  .  .  .  . .
0x24   4 bm  .   4  .  c .  .  y  .  .  .  .  .  . 16  8   .  .  .  .  .  . .
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   visual   x  bf  lv rg d st ge ge  r  g  b a  ax dp st   accum buffs    ms 
 id  dep tp sp sz  l  ci b ro ne ac sz sz sz sz bf th cl  sz  r  g  b  a ns b
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What would be a possible cause and solution for this? The game works on a lot of other cards and hardware, including Nvidia and AMD, and the user has the latest drivers installed for his graphics card.

Comment: Are they doing something silly like running over Remote Desktop, or in a VM, or assuming that the drivers from Windows Update are the "latest"?

Comment: @genpfault Would that be the only reason that something like this could happen? I've seen the same thing happen for multiple users (although it's rare) and they all have AMD cards. I'll ask to make sure.

Comment: The users need to download the latest driver package from amd.com. The version on Windows Update does not support OpenGL. Note that Radeon HD 4200 must use the "legacy" driver package.

Comment: @TheFiddler The user is reporting to have the latest drivers installed from [this page](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download) and that he can play any other (Direct3D) game just fine.

Comment: D3D is independent from OpenGL, i.e. D3D drivers can be installed even if OpenGL drivers are not. This appears to be a driver installation issue, not a software issue. Your best option would be to direct this to AMD support.